# How do I capture indices when a value is assigned in 2D array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, es6-proxy

I have a 2D array.  As you might expect, it is composed of an array of rows with columns in the form of a second array in each row.  When I assign a value to a particular [Row][Column] pair, I would like to have a function that can capture the indices for the element that has been modified and then be able to do something with them.

I have tried to use a proxy, but I can only make it intercept changes that are made to the Row, not the combination of Row and Column.
i.e.

row[3] = {1,2,3,4}; //works!

row[3][2] = 42; //Does not work :/

I have searched extensively in SO, W3Schools, Google, etc. but I cannot find anything that addresses this specific requirement.

```
    var row=new Array();
    for(var loop=0; loop<10;loop++) //Create 10 rows
    {
        row.push(new Array(10)); //10 columns per row for the sake of example
    }

    row[0][0]="Added a Value at (0,0)";
    row[3][7]="Added a value at (3,7)";

    console.log(row[3][7]); //outputs "Added a value at (3,7)" as expected.
```

This works fine and I'm happy with being able to manage data in this grid construct.  I would like to be able to capture when a value is assigned and have access to the two indices so I can perform validation and subsequent activities.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `var row=new Array();` can just be `var row = []`;

Comment: Sure it can.  I'm instantiating with new Array() to prevent (ironically) stack overflows.  The code snippet above is a sample just to demonstrate the structure of the array for clarity.  I don't think that has any impact on the question at hand however.

Comment: There's no such thing as a stack overflow in javascript. Javascript arrays are dynamic objects.

Comment: Thanks for that then.  I was going on the assumption that there was an initial allocation that takes place when instantiating with new Array(n).

Answer (score 0):

Proxy getter/setters only respond to top level property changes. See https://github.com/geuis/bodega/blob/master/src/store.js

Alternatively, you could assign a new Proxy object that has a getter/setter for a property like `row` and/or `column` in each parent array index. That would let you detect when one of those properties is updated.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Unfortunately, javascript is not my strength.  Is there simply no way to trap the event when thing[x][y] is assigned and get the values for x and y?  If not, I can do a function like setValue(x,y,value){} but that seems clunky and will be out of sync if values are changed directly.